# Overflow:hidden in IE doesn't hide image beneath border

Tags: html, internet-explorer, overflow

I'm attempting to slide in images into my main container using some basic
JavaScript on page load.

I've set overflow:hidden on my container div so that the image cannot be
seen until it actually hits the container.

The problem is that in IE doesn't seem to include the border in overflow:hidden,
so the image looks horrible as it slides in over the border. Anyway around this?
I have no problems in other browsers.

My original code:

```
#container{
 border: 5px solid #3A3535;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 padding: 10px 20px 0;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

UPDATE:
I did manage to get it to work. I wrapped the container in a div, removed the border from
container, and added the border to wrapper. Fixes it although I don't know why exactly.

```
#wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border: 5px solid #3A3535;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 16px;

   border-radius: 16px;
}
#container{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 padding: 10px 20px 0;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: IE requires either the height or width to be set for overflow:hidden to work correctly, did you set these?

Comment: If the container doesn't have a background of any kind you could maybe try putting the z-index of the container higher than the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.something {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try setting the width or height to make overflow work.

Comment: I have a width set. I've also tried using z-index, unsucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

try add height for Div like this;

```
height:100%
```